# How can I update the CiviMobile 2.0 extension to the CiviMobileAPI 3.0 extension?

Tags: extension

I had v2 of the CiviMobile extension installed on a WP/Civi site for testing to see how the mobile app would perform. I see that a new version of the app and the extension has been released, so tried to update the extension and just keep getting a fatal error. Looking at the log, it appears to be caused by an incorrect default value that the extension is trying to set in the 'civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages' table:

```
   string(986) "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `entity_table` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `entity_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `send_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_read` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
```

How can I address this and get the extension installed?

Comment: can you add the db error you get when upgrading the extension?

Comment: I see this line:   CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_contact_push_notification_message` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci [nativecode=1067 ** Invalid default value for 'send_date']" (sorry, thought I'd included this in the original post).

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the issue.
As posted here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132951/cant-default-date-to-current-timestamp-in-mysql-5-5
Versions of MySQL from 5.6.x will support this, but I'm currently running 5.5.62 which does not support CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as a default option for a DATETIME. It suggests setting the column type as a TIMESTAMP. I wonder if that will break the extension, though?
Interesting, as I though CiviCRM was now using TIMESTAMP by default across the board.